# What could be the use of synchronizing the simple getter?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

In the famous book "Java concurrency in practice" of Goetz and Co, in one of "good" examples I have found the following:

```
Listing 2.8
@ThreadSafe
public class CachedFactorizer implements Servlet {
    @GuardedBy("this") private BigInteger lastNumber;
    @GuardedBy("this") private BigInteger[] lastFactors;
    @GuardedBy("this") private long hits;
    @GuardedBy("this") private long cacheHits;
    public synchronized long getHits() { return hits; } //  <-- here is the problem!
    public synchronized double getCacheHitRatio() {
        return (double) cacheHits / (double) hits;
    }
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {
        BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
        BigInteger[] factors = null;
            synchronized (this) {
                ++hits;
                if (i.equals(lastNumber)) {
                    ++cacheHits;
                    factors = lastFactors.clone();
                }
            }
            if (factors == null) {
            factors = factor(i);
            synchronized (this) {
            lastNumber = i;
            lastFactors = factors.clone();
        }
    }
    encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
}
```

As far, as I know, and it is said by the authors of the book, one or more commands could be synchronized, if we want them to function as one piece, one atom. It has sense, if the synchronized piece contains more than one atomized operations.

So, what is the sense of synchronizing the

```
return hits;
```

operation? Isn't it atomic **already**?

Comment: Adding the `synchronized` forces a sync of cached data across threads. If it was not there, the variable would have to be `volatile`.

Comment: Atomic implies you cannot read a partially updated value. `++hits` writes a value and `return hits` could therefor return a partially updated value if it is not synchronized against `this`. In practise though that will hardly ever happen because of the reasons Marko mentions in his answer and because most systems are 64-bit. But if this piece of code were to run on a 32-bit system (which needs 2 writes for a 64-bit long-value), `getHits()` could (allthough very unlikely) return a partially updated value if the method is not synchronized against `this`. TL;DR use `AtomicLong`.

Comment: @vanOekel Thank you. Till now I found your explanation the only I have nothing against. Please, could you turn it into an answer?

Comment: @vanOekel BigInteger have *unlimited* length (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), so, your argument prettily works on 64bit systems, too. Simply getting is NOT atomic here.

Comment: @Gangnus Looks like james large did it for me, his answer does a good job of explaining the underlying concepts and methods at work.

Comment: @vanOekel But it was you who had found the answer first. Make the answer and I will move the answer check to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for *mutual exclusion* (i.e., what a Java `synchronized` block provides) is to prevent other threads from seeing data in an inconsistent state while one thread is changing the data.  In order for it to work, *all* threads that access the data have to synchronize on the same object.  The threads that modify the data have to be synchronized, and the threads that merely *look* at the data must be synchronized too.

Your `getHits()` method looks extremely simple, and maybe you are wondering how it could see `hits` in an inconsistent state, but `hits` is a `long`.  The Java Language Specification allows a `long` variable to be updated in two steps because, on 32-bit hardware, there's no other way.  So, without synchronization, on some hardware, it would be possible for getHits() to return a long value that never was assigned to `hits`.  (I.e., it could return a 64-bit value composed of 32 bits from one update and 32 bits from a different update).

By synchronizing both the `getHits()` method *and* the block of code that updates `hits`, your code example prevents that from happening.

---

Synchronization also does what gd1 said:  It can help an update done by a thread running on one CPU to become visible to threads running on other CPUs.  The Java Language Spec says that whatever one thread changes in memory before it exits from a `synchronized` block must become visible to another thread *after* the other thread subsequently enters a `synchronized` block on the same object.

What happens if you don't synchronize depends, once again, on the hardware platform.  On some systems, an update will promptly become visible to other threads even without synchronizations, but on other systems, it could take arbitrarily long before the data are copied over.

Comment: One more argument for the case: It is not my code, it is Goetz's code. And the book was written more than twelve years ago, when 64bit systems were really rare.

Comment: Actually, the hadware platform has far less influence compared to the effects of the optimizing JIT compiler. For HotSpot it is actually the *typical* case that a loop which is supposed to re-read a shared variable on each iteration doesn't do it at all and just acts upon  whatever it read in the first iteration. Canonical example: `while (!done) { ...stuff... }` compiles into `if (!done) while (true) { ...stuff...}`

Answer (score 5):

The simplest answer is this: if the getter wasn't synchronized, the result would be the same as if *nothing* was synchronized.

For example, you could call the getter at any time, even while another thread was in the middle of the `synchronized` block inside the `service` method. A further and less obvious consequence is that the getter would not be guaranteed to observe *any updates at all* of the `hits` field. This is implied by the Java Memory Model and specifically the lack of any *happens before* relationship between writes to that field and the read by the getter.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I still have problems with understanding. If I will do some operations with a getter, I can synchronize the whole block of these operations, including the getter. It will be enough, won't it? And I will have to do it, in accordance to your first argument. So, the synchronization of getter itself seems excessive.

Comment: ...continued...While the getter will be  always used in the synchronized blocks, the second problem will be solved, too. BTW, for me both your arguments seem the same, only formulated in different words. Surely, the problem is that I do not think yet in multithreading terms. Could you add some examples to your answer, please?

Comment: If the getter is always used within a larger synchronized block (this fact was not evident from your question), then indeed the getter does not need to be synchronized on its own. It won't hurt anything, though, because re-acquiring an already acquired lock is virtually a no-op (just a counter is incremented which tracks how many times the same lock was acquired).

Comment: Your second reason seems as a good answer, too. I am sorry I can't mark two answers.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is not `volatile`, thus making it possible for some threads to read a cached (and possibly stale) value unless the access is synchronised. In practical terms, given the fact that the `hits` counter is not going to be used to *make decisions* (i.e. writing on the shared data structure) but just to gather some statistics, it is not a big deal. Nevertheless, it is good practice to protect shared variables and ensure correct data synchronisation.

In that particular case, using an atomic integer could be a better choice IMHO, since the number of hits could be continuously sampled by some performance monitoring thread and you are blocking the entire data structure just to retrieve an integer.